# put text name user: before id on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside my form i have an username textbox that has increment id display on
it, My problem is i want to add a text "user:" before the id like on the sample
pic post under. i tried inserting it on value="user: phpcode" but my increment number doesn't increment, hope you can help me in this one.

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" 
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal1" style=" color:#fff; background:#00bcd4" onClick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value">No</button>
```

here is my sample code inside a modal:

```
<div class="modal fade right" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
 <div class="modal-dialog  modal-full-height modal-right" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header blue accent-1">

        <h3 class="mt-2" style="color:white;"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> New User :</h3>
       <a href="test1.php" button type="btn" class="close"  aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a>      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="md-form mt-0">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="username"  
                id="username" style="width:45%; margin-top:20px;" readonly  value="user:<?php 

           $sql='select max(id)
            from test2';
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            echo $row['0'];
             ?> ">   
                <label for="inputVisitorMD" style="font-size: 1rem; ">Username</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
div class="text-center mt-2">
           <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info"   style="width:98%; ">Log in <i class="fa fa-sign-in ml-1"></i></button>
          </div>
</form>

<!-- Material form grid -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

here is my javascript:

```
<script>
function incrementValue() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('username').value, 10);
    value = value || 0;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('username').value = ("00000" +  value).substr(-5);
    }
</script>
```

[image: this should look like this one on my username field.]

Comment: This isn't really a PHP question, so removing that tag.

Comment: Do you need that to be in the value? Or do you just want it for display purposes?

Comment: Lastly, "my increment doesn't work" is not a clear problem statement.  What specifically happens / doesn't happen?

Comment: the text user? yes i want it to be the username plus the id

Comment: So the php initial value works? You might want to console.log(value) after each line in the js you provided and figure out where it's breaking.

Comment: just the id number only diplay but the text user: is not display when i tried value="user: phpcode select id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution for my question above, just want to share it. :)

```
<button type="button" class="btn"  style=" color:#fff; background:#00bcd4" onClick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value">No</button>
<div class="row">
        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col">
            <!-- Material input -->
            <div class="md-form mt-0">
               <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="id"  id="id" readonly style="width:45%; margin-top:30px;"  value="<?php 

               $sql='select max(id)
                from test2';
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                echo $row['0'];
                 ?> ">
                <label for="inputVisitorMD" style="font-size: 1rem; ">User's ID</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <!-- Material input -->
            <div class="md-form mt-0">
               <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="username"  id="username" style="width:45%; margin-top:20px;" readonly  value="user:00000<?php 

               $sql='select max(id)+1
                from test2';
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                echo $row['0'];
                 ?> ">
               <label for="inputVisitorMD" style="font-size: 1rem; ">Username</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

My javascript:

```
<script>
function incrementValue() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id').value, 10);
    value = value || 0;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('id').value = ("00000" +  value).substr(-5);

 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you never call your increment function from the code you’ve attached. You could solve this directly inside your php (if your running a php server, otherwise this won’t work... just saying because you don’t have a php tag on this question)

So. Are you incrementing this multiple times under “runtime” aka, more times than one. If it’s only going to increment one TIME (not steps. (00001 + steps, 1 time)), you could solve this really easy with php.

Here’s how to do it in backend:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
    <div class="md-form mt-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="username"  
        id="username" style="width:45%; margin-top:20px;" readonly  value="user:<?php 
        $sql='select max(id)
        from test2';
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $int = (int)$row[‘0’] + 1; // <— steps
        $zeros = 5 - strlen(strval($int));
        echo str_repeat(“0”,$zeros) . $int;
            ?> ">    
        <label for="inputVisitorMD" style="font-size: 1rem; ">Username</label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```